# How do i force my code to print in python

Tags: python, encryption, vigenere

I'm having trouble trying to work out an error in my code. It isn't printing the final product and leaving a blank space.

```
playing = True
string = ""
Alphabet = ('z','a','b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z')

while playing == True:
    string = ""
    eord = input('Type "d" to "decrypt" and "e" to "encrypt": ')

    if eord == 'e':
        texte = input ("Type your word to encrypt: ")
        key1 = int(input("Choose a key between 1-26: "))
        for letter in texte:
            number = (ord(letter)) + (key1)
            letter=(chr(number))
            string = (str(string)) + (str(letter))
        print (string)
        keyword = input ("Type 'encrypt' code further or 'decrypt' further: ")

        if keyword == 'encrypt':
            plainText = input("Please enter the plain text: ")
            key = input("Please enter the key: ")
            keyList = []
            keyLength = 0
            while keyLength < len(plainText):
                for char in key:
                     if keyLength < len(plainText):
                         keyList.append(str(char))
                         keyLength = keyLength + 1
                         CipherText = [] 
                         IndexValue = 0
                         keyIncrement = 0
                     for plainTextChar in plainText:
                         IndexValue = Alphabet.index(keyList[keyIncrement]) + Alphabet.index(plainTextChar)
                         while IndexValue > 26:
                             IndexValue = IndexValue - 26
                             CipherText.append(Alphabet[IndexValue])
                             keyIncrement = keyIncrement + 1
                         print (''.join(CipherText))
                         import sys
                         sys.stdout.flush()

                         finish = input('Would you like to go again Y or N')
                         if finish == 'n' or 'N':
                             retry = input ("Would you like to go again? Y or N: ")
                             if retry == 'N' or 'n':
                                 print ("Please exit the window")
                                 import sys
                                 sys.exit()

    elif eord == 'd':
        texd = input ("Type your word to decrypt: ")
        key2 = int(input("Choose a key between 1-16: "))

        for letter in texd:
            number = (ord(letter)) - (key2)
            letter=(chr(number))
            string = (str(string)) + (str(letter))
        print (string)
        keyword = input ("Type 'encrypt' code further or 'decrypt' further: ")

        if keyword == 'decrypt':
             plainText = input("Please enter the plain text: ")
             key = input("Please enter the key: ")
             keyList = []
             keyLength = 0
             while keyLength < len(plainText):
                 for char in key:
                     if keyLength < len(plainText):
                         keyList.append(str(char))
                         keyLength = keyLength - 1
                         completeCipherText = [] 
                         cipherCharIndexValue = 0
                         keyIncrement = 0
                     for plainTextChar in plainText:
                         cipherCharIndexValue = Alphabet.index(keyList[keyIncrement]) + Alphabet.index(plainTextChar)
                         while cipherCharIndexValue > 26:
                             cipherCharIndexValue = cipherCharIndexValue + 26
                             completeCipherText.append(Alphabet[cipherCharIndexValue])
                             keyIncrement = keyIncrement - 1
                         print (''.join(completeCipherText))

                         finish = input('Would you like to go again Y or N')
                         if finish == 'n' or 'N':
                             retry = input ("Would you like to go again? Y or N: ")
                             if retry == 'N' or 'n':
                                 print ("Please exit the window")
                                 import sys
                                 sys.exit()
```

Is there a way i can fix this or force it to print?

Here is the output of the code.

```
Type "d" to "decrypt" and "e" to "encrypt": e
Type your word to encrypt: hello
Choose a key between 1-26: 3
khoor
Type 'encrypt' code further or 'decrypt' further: encrypt
Please enter the plain text: python
Please enter the key: cipher

Would you like to go again Y or N
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the problem with tab spacing. Concretely here:

```
                     while IndexValue > 26:
                         IndexValue = IndexValue - 26
                         CipherText.append(Alphabet[IndexValue])
                         keyIncrement = keyIncrement + 1
```

For the first pass the IndexValue is 19, so it skips also CipherText append. And therefore there is nothing to print out.

Correct indentation here:

```
                     while IndexValue > 26:
                         IndexValue = IndexValue - 26
                     CipherText.append(Alphabet[IndexValue])
                     keyIncrement = keyIncrement + 1
```

Then again you are asking whether to finish when still in the encrypting for loop.

However you have other flaws in your design. If the key is longer than 1 char you end up in Index error due to the keyList having just just 1 item. While you expect more items in keyList in the for loop.

Comment: What do you want to fix when that helped? The tab spacing?

Comment: It helped me understand it better but i can't get the tab spacing correct

Comment: I assume that you want to decrease IndexValue to be in the range of your Alphabet map. So the rest of the while lines are not relevant there and should be spaced to the left.

Comment: Oh ok I see the problem now that @Radek +1 pointed it out. I was looking at other problems in this script.

Comment: Thankyou that fixed that problem. however it now says list index out of range.

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned that in the answer. The problem is in the keyList. I suggest you to start using IDE such as PyCharm and run your code in the debug mode. You will see it clearly there.

Comment: I put the code in pycharm and its says there isnt any suspicious code